# Can I make use of the printscreen button in C# to store an image for later use

Tags: c#, .net

I want to take a screenshot of the form and then use it later to make it the background of the form. this would require the use of PrintScreen button I think. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How May I Capture the Screen in a Bitmap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362986/how-may-i-capture-the-screen-in-a-bitmap)

Comment: @John: It's probably WinForms, as they mentioned the background of a *form*.

Comment: WPF doesn't use the term "form"? In any case, they should probably say.

Answer (score 1):

```
Rectangle area = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(area.Width, area.Height);
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    g.CopyFromScreen(area.Left, area.Height, 0, 0, new Size(area.Width, area.Height));
this.BackgroundImage = bmp;
```

Comment: mun pieng so basically the last line i can use anywhere to make the background as it was at any point of time?

Comment: @olive, yes, you can use it any time anywhere, as long as you still have the `bmp` object on hand.